# google sheets: extract all decimals from a single row and find the average

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet( link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eilz0uOhAnXkc7dpvSktcXv1-S7BWRGw3MZj9kOZGoI/edit?usp=sharing) I need help with. I want to be able to put the average of the scores for topic 1 (eventually I will add more topics but am keeping it simple for the question) in B3. I need to be able to only take the decimal values of scores and count how many instances to get the average. I am new to google sheets. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

I have tried to use the average function but it seems to work for columns and doesn't account for only calculating based on integers.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your simple sample spreadsheet is _too_ simple. Add sample data and also show your desired results.

Comment: Thanks, I added some data. It does seem to work though.  I will try and understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `average(filter())`, like this:

`=iferror( average( filter(C2:K2, C$1:K$1 = "scores") ) )`